# Importing .NET XML doc comment files into Doxygen project

Tags: .net, doxygen, documentation-generation

Anyone know if there is a way to importing .NET XML doc comment files into Doxygen project?

I have a project that uses assemblies that that have XML comment files. I'd like Doygen to pick up that documentation and add it to my doc output.

Answer (score 0):

Doxygen can import external documentation in Tag files.  Tag files are xml, but they're probably a different format than your xml.  You'll need to write a converter if the formats are different.  Generate a tag file from your existing project to get an idea of the required format.

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/external.html